# Getting vertex angles from faces angles in rectangular pyramid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

I have a rectangular pyramid with vertices. I know the angles of their faces (between the faces and the base). But the lengths of sides and height are unknown. How can I know the angle of the edges (between the base and edge) having only the face angles?

From the image, I have the angles $EpF$ and $EqF$, but I need to discover the angles $EBF$ and $CBF$. It is assumed that $AD = BC$ and $AB = DC$.

[image: Pyramid image]

I have found that I have to use the Spherical Law of Cosines, but I have not been able to get my head around the procedure.

Any responses are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write all distances in terms of the height $FE$. Then $$\tan(\angle FqE)=\frac{FE}{qE}\\\tan(\angle FpE)=\frac{FE}{pE}$$
From these equations you can calculate $pE$ and $qE$. You can get then $BE$ from Pythagoras' theorem:
$$BE^2=qE^2+pE^2$$
Then $$\tan(\angle FBE)=\frac{FE}{BE}$$
Note that $FE$ terms will cancel.

Similarly, you can find $Fq$, then $$\tan(\angle CBF)=\frac{Fq}{Bq}=\frac{Fq}{pE}$$